# Can we define new Object[3][] without defining number of columns?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, multidimensional-array

Can someone please help me understand the following code?  I'm new to java, I'm trying to learn Objects[].
This code compiles but retval does not return anything?

1. I've done a lot of search online but can't find why is Object[3][] compiles and does not complain?
2. What does the following code mean?
   (new Object[1])[0] =    tt;
3. How can "retval[0] = new Object[1];" compile if Object is two dimensional array.

   ```
   package Package1;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
   public class Test1
   {

   @Test
   public void NewTest()
   {
       Object[][] retval = new Object[3][];

       int i = 0;
       String methodName = "NewTest";
       String className = this.getClass().toString();
       String desc = "This is a test";

       TestTest tt = new TestTest(methodName, className, desc); 
       System.out.println(tt.str1);
       System.out.println(tt.str2);
       System.out.println(tt.str3);

       (new Object[1])[0] =    tt; 
           retval[0] = new Object[1];    
           retval[1] = new Object[1];
           retval[2] = new Object[1];
           System.out.println("object 0 = " + retval[0]);
           System.out.println("object 1 = " + retval[1]);
           System.out.println("object 2 = " + retval[2]);
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   package Package1;

   public class TestTest 
   {

   String str1 = "apple";
   String str2 = "grape";
   String str3 = "orange";


   public TestTest(String a, String b, String c)
   {
       this.str1 = a;
       this.str2 = b;
       this.str3 = c;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: provide the main method !

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember that creating a 2D array is just making an array of arrays. The length of the arrays within the 2D array is no concern of the array holding them.

   ```
    Object[][] r = new Object[3][];
    Object[] j = new Object[2];

    r[0] = j;
   ```

In this example, we create a 2D array 'r' that can hold 3 arrays. Then we define a 1D array 'j' that can hold 2 Objects. Then we set the first array of 'r' to be 'j'.

However, if you want the length of the arrays within your 2D array to be a specific value; you will have to assign it a value.

Remember that referring to an index in an array is the same no matter the dimension of the array. What the array contains will be different however.